# Jenkins Pipelines - Build multiple projects and deploy once

Tags: jenkins

In the old versions of Jenkins, you add as much builds as you need in the Build section, since I had to build multiple ASP.NET projects my config what like the following :

[image]

How do you add multiple projects in a Pipeline script ?